# How to create a three-column chart?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, charts

I want the data from the Expr1 to be displayed instead of the date. 
I mean VALUE LABEL should be written by Expr1 but not Date.
Does anyone know how to do this?

MY table:

```
-------------------------------------
NameOfRas |     Date    |     Expr1
--------------------------------------
Food      |  07/09/2019 |       13
--------------------------------------
Hotel     |  09/09/2019 |       32
--------------------------------------
Museum    |  12/09/2019 |       52
--------------------------------------
```

And code in C#:

```
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                chart4.Titles.Clear();
                chart4.Titles.Add("Общая диаграмма по датам и видам расходов");
                chart4.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Utopia", 16);
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Rashod.NameOfRas, SpendByDays.Date, SUM(Price) AS Expr1 FROM SpendByDays, Rashod WHERE Rashod.ID_ras = SpendByDays.ID_ras GROUP BY Rashod.NameOfRas, SpendByDays.Date", conn);
                myCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                conn.Open();
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    chart4.Series.Clear();
                    chart4.Series.Add(new Series("")
                    {
                        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
                    });
                    chart4.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Pastel;
                    chart4.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    chart4.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "NameOfRas", myReader, "Date");
                    chart4.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
                    chart4.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    chart4.Visible = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Ничего не найдено", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                myReader.Close();
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: If you want to write a serious question, include sample data, desired results, an explanation of your logic and the SQL code as separate code.

Comment: What 'three' columns? What 'columns'? What red circles?

Comment: I can't upload pic here and I'm here for the first time, that's why...

Comment: Why do you want to upload a picture? What you have here is code and data. Both should be `text`. Also, as an FYI, SQL Server 2008 is now completely out of support now and you should, ideally, be looking at upgrade paths sooner rather than later.

Comment: I fixed the messag

Comment: So, you set 'NameOfRas' and 'Date' as x- and y-values. If ypu want 'Expr1' set that to be the y-member??

Comment: Just noticed, you should really stop using 30 year old standards for Joins. It was replaced 27 here's ago. [bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)